# Web application UI tool to use with PHP

Tags: php, html, user-interface, web-applications

i am new in PHP and i'm just asking what tool can i use to create my webstite using PHP and MYsql as my database so that i don't have to write the HTML code myself some FREE tool that provides drags and drops or something so that i'm concerned only by the business behind each part , PHP work, any help? :)

Comment: Though I loathe it, [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html) springs to mind.

Comment: thanks but if there is some free tool to use it will be great :)

Comment: @HossamKhaledZaky Everything is free ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Eclipse.  It is free, it's not WYSIWYG, but it does include very good auto complete features.  I'm not sure that you will be able to drag and drop an e-commerce solution, for example, from any editor, but there are plenty of good code samples you can cut and paste and begin to work from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this editor: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quanta_Plus

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Weebly](http://www.weebly.com/).

> [Weebly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weebly) is an online, free widget-based Web site creator. It uses a widget-style format, allowing
>   users to create pages with only a few clicks by dragging and dropping
>   different page elements

You can try it for free, and [pay the hosting](http://designers.weebly.com/designer_pricing.php).

There is no PHP integration support tough.

Answer (score 0):

[Agile Toolkit](http://agiletoolkit.org/) allows you to develop web app without writing HTML, but you still need to write some PHP code and learn. If you are looking for UI-only solutions, look at [Drupal](http://drupal.org/).